# How do I get Electron to open each new Window in a separate process?

Tags: javascript, electron

Chromium runs various windows in different processes through some heuristic (like based on different domains etc). In Electron I'd like to be able to force a window into a separate render process from other windows.

[Looking through the docs for `BrowserWindow` I don't see way](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/).

Is there a way to force a BrowserWindow to use a separate process from other windows in Electron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electron always creates a separate process for each BrowserWindow and WebView, unless you specifically change the Chromium process model via a flag (but that's not advisable as it'll break things).